# Function overload resolution trouble

Tags: c++

Over the weekend, I had specific problem with function overload resolution that I can't seem to solve.
The code below is a distillation of the problem:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
void f(const T& t)
{
    cout << "In template function." << endl;
}

class C
{
public:
    void f() { cout << "In class function." << endl; }
    void g() { int i=0; f(i); }
    void h() { int i=0; f<int>(i); }
    void i() { extern void f(int); int i=0; f(i); }
};

int main()
{
    cout << "Test" << endl;
    C c;
    c.i();
    return 0;
}
```

1) C::g won't compile because the compiler won't try the template. It just complains that there is no C::f to match.

2) C::h won't compile for no reason that is obvious to me. The message is "expected primary-expression before 'int'"

3) C::i will compile, but (after commenting out g and h) it won't link to anything. I think I understand this: the extern is forcing the linker to look into another compilation unit, but any template definition would be in this compilation unit.

I would appreciate any clarification on the reasons for 1 and 2. Also, ultimately, can someone suggest a way to get this to work that doesn't involve creating another compilation unit?

Comment: +1 for providing a distilled, minimal, complete program that demonstrates the problem. http://sscce.org/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look here: http://ideone.com/zs9Ar

Output:

> Test
>   In template function.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
void f(const T& t)
{
    cout << "In template function." << endl;
}

class C
{
public:
    void f() { cout << "In class function." << endl; }
    void g() { using ::f; int i=0; f(i); }
};

int main()
{
    cout << "Test" << endl;
    C c;
    c.g();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Likely it is finding `C::f` instead of global `f`. Use `::f<int>(i)`.

Answer (score 0):

Functions with the same name will **hide** other functions of the same name when they have different scopes, even if they have different signatures.

Instead of using a template for the first f, you could just do `f(int)` and the result would be the same for #1(the C::f() hides the  ::f(int)).

One solution is to add "::" before the name to force the global namespace.
Another solution would be to change the names.

Comment: The first sentence must have something to do with scope, otherwise you're saying function overloading is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Names in a smaller scope hide names in an outer scope.

Use `::f` to indicate global namespace.

In `i()` you declare a function called `f`, but indeed there is no definition (it is not the same as the template), so you get a linker error.

Answer (score 0):

C++ is somewhat "greedy" when trying to find functions. As soon as it finds a matching function *name* in the current scope (in this case, `class C`) it stops and then tries to match the parameters. If the parameters don't match, it won't try additional scopes. I assume this was to keep compiler writers sane. That's why `g` doesn't compile.

The same thing applies to `h`. It sees a non-template function `f` in the class scope and gets confused. It thinks you're trying to do a `<` comparison against the function `C::f`.

In both cases you can use `::f` to qualify the name to the global scope.